# Dell vFlash Health: Critical. Is it toast?

Tags: dell, drac, sd-card

I have just bought a dell R610 server which had a vFlash card included. Upon trying to initilize the dell vFlash I get the message that the health of the vFlash card is critical and it couldn't initialize. Is there anything that can be done to rescue it or is it just toast?

[image]

Anything I should investigate?

Thanks,
   Jas

Comment: Is this server brand new? Is this server covered under a Dell service contract? If so, call Dell technical support.

Comment: @joeqwerty with a PERC6 card, this is at least 2 generations ago.@sysjas - sorry, not familiar with vFlash, but I'll look into it when I'm in office!

Comment: @joeqwerty The server is second hand... I'll contact the seller, but just wanted to check out the details behind the vFlash. I haven't used vFlash before but am eager to have the functionality... It could be that I just need to buy another card or it could be something else hence the questions. Thanks, Jas